# "Address already in use" error from socket bind, when ports are not being used

Tags: networking, centos, redhat, tcpip, socket

I can not bind (using C or python sockets) to any port in the range: 59969-60000

Using lsof, netstat and fuser I do not see any processes using these ports.

Other ports such as 59900-59968 and 60001-60009 I can bind to them.

My OS: is CentOS release 5.5 (Final) 2.6.18-194.3.1.el5

There must be something missing?  Anyone have any idea how to debug why this port range is not usable?

Cheers,
Ivan

Comment: Post the code. Also try "nc -l 60000" to rule out your code.

Comment: Also look at `netstat -tap` (as root), maybe some other program like inetd or xinetd is listening on ports in that range.

Comment: Should have been placed on stackoverflow.  too old to migrate.

Answer (score 1):

I would check local firewall settings. Since iptables is not a separate process it will not usually show up in lsof, netstat, and fuser.
What is the output to "sudo iptables -L -n"?